# connect input from appended customComponent to object

Tags: javascript, html, input, custom-component

I'm appending custom-components per key:value pair of objects. Now I'd like to pass the new value onChange to the object. And I'd need the functions to be reusable.

I've been fiddling around with this for a while (a long while) to make it somehow display the props, but I assume I have set it up wrong. The object is not really connected to the created elements. It should finally display settings for SVG-elements, that's why I tried with key:value I extract there via getters for the moment)
I'm actually out of charge:

main.js

```js
window.onload = () => {

        let testObj = {
            id: 'SVG0',
            x1: '90',
            y1: '90',
            x2: '246',
            y2: '246'
        }
        let pair;
        class SettingsTest extends HTMLElement {

            connectedCallback() {
                let key = pair.k;
                let value = pair.v;

                this.innerHTML =
                    `<div class="input-element" style="margin-bottom: 30px; width: 100px">
                    <div>
                        <label class="attributes" data-shrink="true">${key}</label>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input aria-invalid="false" type="text" class="propValues" value=${value}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
            }
        };
        customElements.define('settings-test', SettingsTest);

        function appendComponents(obj, tag, parent) {
            const p = document.getElementById(parent);
            p.replaceChildren()

            Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {

                pair = { k: [ key ], v: obj[ key ] }
                newEl = document.createElement(tag);
                newEl.setAttribute('id', `prop${index}`);
                p.appendChild(newEl);

                return pair;
            })

        };
       appendComponents(testObj, 'settings-test', 'container') 
       }
```

```css
input {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#a5bae3;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #a5bae3;
    width: 90%;
    align-items:baseline;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
 *:focus {
    outline: none;
    color:blue
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Test Input FROM CUSTOM</title>
     <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rework your code into an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help us execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: great suggestion. Didn't know how to. Would I have to delete the original question to not duplicate the code? It seems I'm not able to delete that code, so now it shows twice

Comment: Edit your question, delete the last part (your hardcoded code)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman LOL...finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **abusing** your **global variable** `pair` to set content inside your component. This works in simple code; but will blow up in your face in real applications.

Key with Web Components is: You communicate data with `attributes` or `properties` (or `Events`)

Here is your code, simplified, to show the concept

```js
let testObj = {
  id: 'SVG0',
  x1: '90',
  y1: '90',
  x2: '246',
  y2: '246'
}

customElements.define('settings-test', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<br>key:${this.getAttribute("key")} value: ${this.value}`;
  }
});

let tags = Object.entries(testObj).map(([key,value], index) => {
  newEl = document.createElement("settings-test");
  newEl.setAttribute('id', `prop${index}`);
  newEl.setAttribute('key', key); // attribute
  newEl.value = value; // property
  return newEl;
});

document.body.append(...tags);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I feared, but couldn't think of another way. Thanks a ton!
I'll just try it out.
... and very nice! (t was my first rodeo with such, and I felt I were doing really complicated)

Comment: ... and especially *wrong*